# IpOverUsbSvc not found while deploying Windows Phone 8.1 app in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-services, windows-10

I am trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 app in **Windows 10**. I am getting the following errors:

> Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.
>
> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device':
> SmartDeviceException - Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console.

My Lumia phone is connected and is accessible from Windows File Explorer.

I have checked in services for the **IpOverUsbSvc** service, but its not there. So I also checked in powershell: `get-service IpOverUsbSvc`

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  IpOverUsbSvc       Windows Phone IP over USB Transport...
```

I was not getting these errors while I was using Windows 8.1. It seems like this service is not available in Windows 10.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using an insider build of Windows 10 Mobile? Can you tell me the build number?

Comment: @DanielJacobson In my mobile I have windows 8.1 and in my laptop I hv windows 10.0 (Build 10240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced similar one when I've upgrade my dev system from 10166 to 10240 - IpOverUsbSvc does not start.

It seems that... in some cases, the registration info of ipoverusbsvc is corrupted. To fix it, just put a correct info to the registry.

You can find following link that ms guy upload the correct .reg file to his onedrive.

[[UWP][SDK]IpOverUsbSvc service missing in windows 10 RC (Build 10240)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74fafd96-50cf-4d77-9d7a-41620c5487a5/)

Comment: I have already installed this reg file..but its not working still.

Comment: In 2018 versions of Windows10 that Regedit file no longer works - the service will not start

Answer (score 11):

I have run that reg file, but for me it still didn't work. When I tried to run this manually it works:

[image]

Comment: I didn't have to run the reg file named in another answer. Just run it manually solved my problem.

Comment: Works completely !

Answer (score 3):

The problem in my case was that the service didn't exist. I used [Microsoft Guy's reg update file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/74fafd96-50cf-4d77-9d7a-41620c5487a5/uwpsdkipoverusbsvc-service-missing-in-windows-10-rc-build-10240?forum=wpdevelop)

Then, rebooted my computer and service showed up. However, I couldn't start the service as the executable was missing.

I tried removing and reinstalling the Windows 10 SDK to no avail.

Then I found out that in Visual Studio Installer / Modify / Individual Package "USB Device Connectivity" was not installed.

That option checked installs the missing file.

Make sure that your services manager is closed during the installation process.

After installing the missing component you will be able to debug on win 10 device over usb.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem because of 2 Visual Studio editions installed in parallel with different set of features. Repair of Visual Studio 2013 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "ARM" with "x86" or "x64" in "Active solution platforms" in "Configuration Manager" in VS2017